# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://russian.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Russian Language has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Dmitry]

[image: shabunc]

[image: Quassnoi]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://russian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

And - congratulations to your community on its successful graduation election.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://russian.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4527411812106240).

Comment: "Meet the new boss / Same as the old boss", eh? (I don't think they're "new moderators" joining "the existing crew", in this case :P)

Comment: LOL at the comment by V2Blast!